# Action of Steenrod algebra on Chern classes

Tags: characteristic-classes, chern-classes, steenrod-algebra, stiefel-whitney

This is question about result from Brown and Peterson *$H^*(MO)$ as an algebra over the Steenrod algebra*. Unfortunately, the paper is not available on the Internet, so I can't find the proof.

One of results of the paper is the following.
Let $w_n^* \in H_{n}(BO;\mathbb F_2)$ be the dual of Stiefel-Whitney class $w_n$ with respect to the basis of Stiefel-Whitney monomials. Denote by $z_n \in H_*(MO; \mathbb F_2)$ its image under the Thom isomorphism. Then the coaction $\rho\colon H_*(MO; \mathbb F_2) \to \mathfrak A_2^*\otimes H_*(MO; \mathbb F_2)$ maps $z_{2^j-1}$ to
$\sum\limits_{i=0}^j \zeta_i \otimes z_{2^{j-i}-1}^{2^i}$,
where $\zeta_i$ is the conjugate of Milnor's $\xi$'s. (Thanks to John Greenwood for corrections!)

**Questions:**

> 1) How to prove this result?
>
> 2) Does the similar formula hold for the coaction of the mod $p$ Steenrod algebra on the Chern classes?
>
> 3) Not exactly about result* Is there any way to get the paper?
>
> MR0761717 Brown, E. H., Jr.(1-BRND); Peterson, F. P.(1-MIT) H∗(MO) as
>   an algebra over the Steenrod algebra. Conference on homotopy theory
>   (Evanston, Ill., 1974), 11–19, Notas Mat. Simpos., 1, Soc. Mat.
>   Mexicana, México, 1975. 55S99 (Thanks to Ben McKay!)

**UPD:**
In [this](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/mathematical-proceedings-of-the-cambridge-philosophical-society/article/homology-of-bo-and-some-results-about-the-steenrod-algebra/78669DCD6CAE10887F0D79D1F96F7C66) paper Brown, Davis and Peterson give quite similar description,
but for the right coaction in $BO$ and $BU$:
\begin{equation}
\rho(\sum_{i=0} w_i^*) = \sum_{i=0} w_i^*\otimes (\sum_{j=0}\zeta_j)^{i-1}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\rho(\sum_{i=0} c_i^*) = - 1\otimes (\sum_{j=0}\zeta_j)^{-1} + \sum_{i=1} c_i^*\otimes (\sum_{j=0}\zeta_j)^{i-1}
\end{equation}

> Is there any way to rewrite the latter for the left coaction?

Comment: MR0761717 
Brown, E. H., Jr.(1-BRND); Peterson, F. P.(1-MIT)
H∗(MO) as an algebra over the Steenrod algebra. Conference on homotopy theory (Evanston, Ill., 1974), 11–19,
Notas Mat. Simpos., 1, Soc. Mat. Mexicana, México, 1975.
55S99

Comment: @BenMcKay Yes, I know that this paper is contained there, but, unfortunately, this journal isn't available online
do you have the pdf?

Comment: no, sorry, I just wanted readers of the question to be clear about what the problem is. Maybe someone connected to Mexico will have a solution.

Comment: @BenMcKay Thank you! I've added this information to the question.

Comment: Yours \omega_i^* are exactly primitive homology classes and given by newton polynomials by s(t)=log(b(t))'

Comment: 2. coaction on BO is given by 
\rho: b(t) -> b(\xi(t))
where b = 1+b_1 t+.. and \xi(t)=t+\xi_1 t^2 +...

coaction from MO by similar formula: 
\beta(t) -> \beta(\xi(t)) \xi(t) / t
this way you obtain the last formula for \rho(\omega) for BO and in terms of the Thom-isomorphism with MO

Comment: 3. Milnor conjugates are given by \zeta(t) via \xi(t)-series composition-inverse. 
you can obtain them in expansion for coaction naturally when \rho applied to compositional-inverse s^{-1}:
\rho: s^{-1}(t) -> \zeta(s^{-1}(t))
this way your first formula seems to be false for s(t), but work fine for s^{-1}(t)

Comment: 4. when your right action is _defined_ by anti-automorphism of the left-action then for correct left-action formula you have to substitute expressions for \zeta in terms of \xi and write them on the left hand side of \otimes:) it's tautology, but I dont see another way for interpretation

Answer (score 2):

The elements $z_n$ of $(H\mathbb{F}_2)_*MO$ that you described come from classes in $(H\mathbb{F}_2)_*\mathbb{RP}^\infty$ (namely ones that are dual to powers of the first Stiefel-Whitney class) under the inclusion $\mathbb{RP}^\infty\rightarrow \Sigma MO$ so the coaction formula follows from the coaction formula on $H_*\mathbb{RP}^\infty$.

The same argument works at larger primes with $MO$ replaced by $MU$, $\mathbb{RP}^\infty$ replaced by $\mathbb{CP}^\infty$, and Stiefel-Whitney replaced by Chern.

I couldn't find anything about that paper though.

Comment: This is not quite true. The dual to Stiefel-Whitney class $w_n$ with $n\geqslant 2$ don't come from classes in $H_*(\mathbb R P^\infty; \mathbb F_2)$. The latter contains only duals to degrees of the first Stiefel-Whitney class.

Comment: It is correct (see e.g. Adams "stable homotopy and generalised homology" page 8 for the MU version. I know it seems counterintuitive since the classes start out being dual only to powers of the first Stiefel-Whitney class. But once they arrive in $H_*MU$ they are actually polynomial generators for it.

Comment: Classes $b_i \in H_*(MU)$ are the images of the dual to the Milnor genus classes. And the coaction maps is not the described one, but $\rho(b_i) = \sum_j (\sum_k \xi_k)^{j+1}_{2(i-j)} \otimes b_j$.

Comment: @SemyonAbramyan Sorry perhaps I was too brief. I don't claim that the $b_n$ are equal to your $z_n$. I am just pointing out that the coaction of the dual Steenrod algebra in $H_*MO$ is completely determined by the coaction in $H_*\mathbb{RP}^\infty$ (and as you pointed out in your comment, easily described on the $b_n$) so it is a matter of pure algebra to get the formula on the $z_n$.

Comment: of course the coaction in $H_*(MO)$ and $H_*(MU)$ is determined by the coaction in $H_*(\mathbb R P^\infty)$ and $H_*(\mathbb C P^\infty)$, but it is not clear for me how to write down explicit formulae for $z_n$ in terms of classical polynomial generators of $H_*(\mathbb R P^\infty)$ or $H_*(\mathbb C P^\infty)$. If you know how, it will be really helpful!

Comment: @SemyonAbramyan  Ok I see, so your $z_n$ is the $n$th- Newton polynomial in the $b_j$, which follows from page 11 of the Adams reference where he describes the dual situation.